# How to update a document with other documents that have a matching field via mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, shell

I inserted the records below and am trying to insert all documents from tasksdemo into jobsdemo where tasksdemo job field matches jobsdemo. Is there a way to do this in one command from the shell?

```
db.jobsdemo.insert({name:"test1", iScheduled : true, startDate : new Date("2017-09-01T17:58:29.285Z"), endDate: new Date("2017-09-10T17:58:29.285Z") , dueDate: new Date("2017-09-10T17:58:29.285Z"), isSoftDueDate: false, softDateCushion: 10, client: "Mel’s House of Hair"})
db.jobsdemo.insert({name:"test2", iScheduled : true, startDate : new Date("2017-09-01T17:58:29.285Z"), endDate: new Date("2017-09-10T17:58:29.285Z") , dueDate: new Date("2017-09-11T17:58:29.285Z"), isSoftDueDate: true, softDateCushion: 10, client: "Crasco"})
```

and then the following:

```
db.tasksdemo.insert({job:"test1", iScheduled : true, startDate : new Date("2017-09-02 17:58"), duration: 127})
db.tasksdemo.insert({job:"test1", iScheduled : true, startDate : new Date("2017-09-02 10:22"), duration: 56})
db.tasksdemo.insert({job:"test1", iScheduled : true, startDate : new Date("2017-09-02 10:22"), duration: 116})
db.tasksdemo.insert({job:"test1", iScheduled : true, startDate : new Date("2017-09-09 13:45"), duration: 149})
db.tasksdemo.insert({job:"test1", iScheduled : true, startDate : new Date("2017-09-10 16:00"), duration: 89})


db.tasksdemo.insert({job:"test2", iScheduled : true, startDate : new Date("2017-09-03 12:58"), duration: 186})
db.tasksdemo.insert({job:"test2", iScheduled : true, startDate : new Date("2017-09-05 09:55"), duration: 158})
db.tasksdemo.insert({job:"test2", iScheduled : true, startDate : new Date("2017-09-08 13:03"), duration: 40})
db.tasksdemo.insert({job:"test2", iScheduled : true, startDate : new Date("2017-09-09 09:12"), duration: 77})
db.tasksdemo.insert({job:"test2", iScheduled : true, startDate : new Date("2017-09-09 12:55"), duration: 181})
db.tasksdemo.insert({job:"test2", iScheduled : true, startDate : new Date("2017-09-10 16:00"), duration: 64})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
db.jobsdemo.insert(db.tasksdemo.find().toArray());
```